# Angular js $http.get in $http.get not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have user list,I will show this users . User have unreaded messages and not writen meal list, I want to make tow http.get in main http.get request to get needed information, but my problem is that it works asynchronously, so unreadmessage and week values doesn't change. How can I do it. Thanks in advance

```
$http.get('http://example.com/users').success(function(response){         
            var data=response;
            if(data==null || data.length<=0){
                return;
            }
            var date2 = new Date();

            var users=[];

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                var diffDays=0;

                if(data[i].uyelikBaslangicTarihi=="0"){                             
                    continue;
                }
                var from = data[i].uyelikBaslangicTarihi.substring(0,10).split("/");                    
                var date1 = new Date(from[2], (from[1] - 1), from[0]);                  
                var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
                diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
                if(diffDays>28 || diffDays<0){                              
                    continue;
                }
                var week=diffDays/7;
                week=parseInt(week);
                if(diffDays/7>0)
                    week++;                     
                if(week!=0)
                    week--;
                var unloadweek=week+1;
                var unreadmessage=0;


                $http.get('http://example.com/menus?userId=' + data[i]._id + '&haftaSayisi=' + week).success(function(response){        
                    if(response==null || response.length==0){unloadweek= "";}
                    else{unloadweek= week;}          
                });
                $http.get('http://example.com/sorus?userId=' + data[i]._id + '&okundu=0').success(function(response){   
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response==null){ unreadmessage= 0;}
                    else{unreadmessage = response.length;}       
                });
                var color="white"       

                var gender='mars'   

                if(data[i].cinsiyet=="Kadın")
                    gender='venus';
                var user={
                    id:data[i]._id,
                    name:data[i].ad,
                    gender:gender,
                    weight:data[i].kilo,
                    height:data[i].boy,
                    birthday:data[i].dogum_tarihi,
                    email:data[i].email,
                    src:"http://example.com/images/"+data[i]._id+".jpeg",
                    color:color,
                    week:unloadweek,
                    unreadmessage:unreadmessage
                }
                if(data[i].uyelikBaslangicTarihi!="" && data[i].uyelikBaslangicTarihi!="0" && data[i].rol!="admin")
                    users.push(user);

            }
            $scope.customers=users;



        })
        .error(function(err){
           alert("hata");
        }
```

)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please try to reword. See also [ask]. I have not bothered to read your code as it seems like it is just a dump of everything you have in your component, not an [mcve] which describes the problem you are facing.

Comment: the code in the function occuring after the $http.get will execute before the $http.get returns.

Comment: You&#39;re using angular so if you change a variable defined in your scope, so if you change your user content, the change is propaged everywhere. I'm not sur undertand your question

Comment: $http.get makes an asynchronous call and code continues to run while it executes in the background. There are a lot of issues with your code and the overall approach. I'd recommend you look into an angularjs style guide for best practices and adapt from there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to chain your http requests and the promises properly. Please refer to the documentation (see below).

Also, please respect the scope of you variables in that context - 
the `unloadweek` variable is defined before the get and then used within the next $http.get resolve function - and all that within the for loop.

Not sure if there might also be a problem with you code structure :) Would suggest to improve with that ;-)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q